# Groovy REST api for POST with body as JSON

Tags: json, rest, groovy

I have been trying to perform a POST to JasperReports using Groovy with no success.

GET works fine and I can authenticate with success.

I cannot understand what the problem is with the following code :

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

def restV2 = new RESTClient( 'http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/' )
restV2.auth.basic "superuser", "superuser"

def resp = restV2.post(
        path : 'organizations',
        contentType:JSON,
        requestContentType : JSON,
        body : [id:'1234567891234',
                alias:'FictiefeNet',
                tenantName:'FictiefeNet',
                tenantDesc:'FictiefeNet B.V.',
                theme:'default']
)
```

The output is :

```
Caught: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
        at groovyx.net.http.EncoderRegistry.encodeJSON(EncoderRegistry.java:301)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.encodeBody(HTTPBuilder.java:1268)
        at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:442)
        at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:141)
        at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$post.call(Unknown Source)
        at setOrg.run(setOrg.groovy:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
        ... 6 more
```

I am sure the body is formatted correctly as the POST call works just fine from postman (REST API extention for chrome).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add commons-lang to your classpath?

Comment: That was it! It actually has to be commons-lang v 2.5. It does not work with version 3 Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgiosGkinis, `ClassNotFoundException` often point to misconfigured classpath.